# Performance issues when resizing MapView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mapkit, mkmapview

I’m trying to achieve vertical split view in SwiftUI. There are two views, top one is Map (MKMapView actually, wrapped with UIViewRepresentable) and bottom one for this example could be Color.red. Between them there’s a handle to resize the proportions. Initial proportions are 0.3 of height for bottom, 0.7 for map. When resizing map frame, it feels choppy and slow. Replacing MapView with any other view does not produce the same issue.

Issue appears only on my real device (iPhone 11 Pro Max) simulator works fine.

Comment: what you are showing inside map?

Comment: Only annotations. Issue also happens when there's nothing on the Map. Offsetting it in Y axis does not produce the same lag as changing it's frame.